# How should I properly log my class container?

Tags: python, logging

I have the  following situation:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, log = True):
        self.log = log

    def __call__(self):
        if self.log:
             self.log ='\n'    # whatever no-Null string to reinitialize the log attribute at each call
        do_things()
             self.log += 'I did things'

class B()
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A(log = True) 
        self.log_master = []

    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(num):
            self.a()
            self.log_master.append(a.log)
            self.log_master.append('other things')
        save_to_file(self.log_master)
```

So I have a class `B` which is initialized with an instance of class `A`. `B` calls `A`. When the class `A` is called it initializes a string which serve as a container to log the operations. When call ends, `B` checks `A`'s log string and append it to `log_master`, besides other things. At the end of everything `log_master` is saved to file. Basically I have two classes, one of which serve as a container for an instance of the other. Both 'collaborate' at writing a log file.

I can feel the horror with this approach. My `A` code is cluttered with ugly "if self.log: ..". What is the right approach to produce a decent and customizable logfile?

Comment: Why dont you use python's inbuild file logger?

Comment: I've given the docs a read but the thing looks convolved and not easy to implement for my case. Do you have any particular resource to recommend? Thank you @AmitNanaware

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do here would definitely be easier by using the built-in logging module. If for some reason you don't want to write logs immediately to file there is a `MemoryHandler` in the logging module specifically for that. Basically you could write all of A's logs to one such Memoryhandler, and after you are done with A have the target Handler take care of the what to do with those collected logs, and in what format/order to log them.